# Does copper wire get sold as flat straps to reduce inductance?

Tags: grounding, safety

The extra book (11-9) safety section mentions that a "large diameter wire, or even better, a wide flat strap, has the lowest inductance and makes the best ground connection." Does anyone actually have conductive wire in that shape to reduce inductance or am I getting something mixed up here?

Comment: Yes. See [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=copper+earth+strap&atb=v179-1&iax=images&ia=images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy copper strap at [Georgia Copper](https://www.gacopper.com). There are other sources, such as [DX Engineering's Georgia Copper page](https://www.dxengineering.com/search/brand/georgia-copper).

[image: 1 inch wide copper grounding strap]

For RF, it is better to use this copper sheet metal strap wherever possible. The flexible braided stuff eventually becomes more lossy as corrosion and oxidation sets in and the small wires become significantly insulated from each other.

From http://www.w8ji.com/ground_systems.htm:

> ... A good [lightning] ground must have a very low impedance over a very wide frequency range. This rules out thin wires, and loosely woven braided conductors should be avoided. The very best ground leads are solid wide smooth surfaces, although braiding sometimes must be used in areas that demand conductor flexibility.